# Let $f: (\mathbb{Z}_{24}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_{36}, +)$ be a group homomorphism. How many elements are there in the kernel of $f$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic, group-homomorphism

Let  $f: (\mathbb{Z}_{24}, +) \rightarrow (\mathbb{Z}_{36}, +)$
be a group homomorphism. If the image of $f$ contains exactly $2$ elements, how many elements are there in the kernel of $f$?

**What I know:**

Let $f : G \to H$ be a group homomorphism between two finite groups. Then we
have $$|G| = |\ker(f )| \times |{\rm im}(f )|$$
$$|G|= |\ker(f )|  \times  2$$

However I don't know how to work out $|G|$ for my question.

Comment: If $G=\mathbb Z/{24}\mathbb Z$, then $|G|=24$

Comment: You need to know what $\Bbb Z_{24}$ is. Do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of $G$ is 24 [why is this], so plugging this into your equation $|G| =$ $|$ker$(f)| \times |$Im$(f)|$ yields $24 =$ $|$ker$(f)| \times 2$ or $|$ker$(f)| = 12.$

Comment: Do you just take the order of the first $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Did you make a typo. for the answer to $|\ker (f)|$?

Answer (score 0):

By the first isomorphism theorem, $G/\rm{ker}f\cong\rm{im}f$.  So, $24/|\rm{ker}f|=2$.  Thus $|\rm{ker}f|=12$.